# Dealing with "HTTP request timed out. Exiting." when building a large aspnet project for Docker

Tags: asp.net, powershell, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, boot2docker

I have a multi-project aspnet solution using MVC6

The Solution file is split into three projects

```
 sln
 +---- Model
 +---- API
 +---- Web
```

The Docker file lives in the same folder as the SLN file and has the following content

```
 FROM microsoft/aspnet
 COPY . /app
 WORKDIR /app/Web
 RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

 EXPOSE 5004
 ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", ".", "kestrel" ]
```

The issue when I run `docker build -t myapp .` from the powershell command line is the build process begins to time out.

```
PS C:\www\MyApp> docker build -t myapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 19.11 MB
Step 0 : FROM microsoft/aspnet
---> 0835b01cd4f8
Step 1 : COPY . /app
---> Using cache
---> 56c449a3d847
Step 2 : WORKDIR /app/Web
---> Using cache
---> 8f43b8786452
Step 3 : RUN dnu restore
---> Running in d43e0c4b42c8
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Mono-x64-1.0.0-beta7-15532

GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json 555ms
Restoring packages for /app/Web/project.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.diagnostics/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.mvc.taghelpers/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.server.iis/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.server.weblistener/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.staticfiles/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.tooling.razor/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.framework.configuration.json/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.framework.logging/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.framework.logging.console/index.json
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.visualstudio.web.browserlink.loader/index.json
OK https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.diagnostics/index.json 6436ms
```

[...  AFTER HUNDREDS OF LINES OF INITIAL SUCCESS ...]
disaster strikes!

```
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.win32.registry/4.0.0-beta-23109/microsoft.win32.registry.4.0.0-beta-23109.nupkg
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.Common
HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/system.io.filesystem/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.Abstractions
HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/system.resources.resourcemanager/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel
HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.debug/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery
HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
```

[ ... RESULTING IN MANY LINES OF ... ]

```
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.win32.primitives/index.json
Error: DownloadPackageAsync: https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.http.abstractions/1.0.0-beta6/microsoft.aspnet.http.abstractions.1.0.0-beta6.nupkg
HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
----------
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

[ ... AND EVENTUALLY ... ]

```
----------
Restore failed
A task was canceled.

NuGet Config files used:
    /root/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/
GET https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates/index.json
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
The command 'dnu restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I've tried hunting about for answers on this and doing things like restarting the docker machine or deleting and rebuilding it (in kitematic), but even if those solutions DID work (they don't) that solution seems less than ideal.

Note that I've also attempted to view the urls that are timing out, from the very same machine that is timing out and they do work from windows.

I assume that may mean that the virtualbox docker machine is perhaps timing out, saturating the number of connections it can open or *something*

The docker image is the default boot2docker linux instance that comes with the docker toolbox.

It is running on windows 10.

Alternatively, if I run the same setup and commands on a new aspnet project (as created using the `yo aspnet` generator), docker does indeed successfully build the project.

Any help in figuring out how to build a docker image would be very much appreciated.